# Unity - Loading bar often goes from 0% to 100% directly, while loading (C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a **loading bar** following [Brackeys](https://www.youtube.com/user/Brackeys)' tutorial *[here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YMj2qPq9CP8)* (and have changed a few things later). I noticed that when I load a level, and my loading bar comes out, it first shows *0%*, waits, then directly *100%* - **without intermediate values**!.

I'm guessing it could be due to some **lag** that occurs because the game is already using a lot of hardware, and hasn't left enough power for the rest of the processes, because I tried making it load while doing other things at the same time.

Here is the code that **loads the level** and **changes the slider's value**:

```cs
    public void LoadLevel(int sceneIndex) {
        StartCoroutine(StartFadeThenLoadLevel(sceneIndex));
    }

    IEnumerator StartFadeThenLoadLevel(int sceneIndex)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.9f);
        StartCoroutine(LoadAsynchronously(sceneIndex));
    }

    IEnumerator LoadAsynchronously(int sceneIndex) {
        yield return null;

        AsyncOperation operation = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(sceneIndex);

        loadingScreen.SetActive(true);
        chooseLevel.SetActive(false);

        while (!operation.isDone) {
            float progress = Mathf.Clamp01(operation.progress / 0.12f);

            if (progress > 1) progress = 1;

            slider.value = progress;
            progressText.text = (int)(progress * 100f) + "%";

            yield return null;
        }
    }
```

> I saw that this mostly happens on **more powerful phones**, when it **doesn't take more than a second** to load the scene, than in **older** (slower) **ones**.

**How can I fix this?** I would like to have a very smooth loading bar that updates at least every 5%!

Thanks in advance for any help!

**Edit**: I added an FPS counter (Graphy) and i saw that there was a huge frame drop down to 1fps. That is probably what causes everything! Is there any way to prevent that?
(If you think this is likely to be the problem, please answer this question instead of the main one!)

Comment: how many times does your while loop, loop with return null, once? regardless of the if block.

Comment: @Seabizkit it usually only has time to loop twice, as the frame rate is extremely low while loading the scene.

Comment: just wrote a console app, to prove im not going mad. your while loop should not contain a "return" unless you are wanting to exit out of the loop.

Comment: @Seabizkit Deleting the ```yield return null;``` in the while loop can't work!

Comment: Why do you divide progress by 0.12?

Answer (score 3):

`int progress` is 0 when `operation.progress <= 0` and it is 1 when `operation.progress > 0`.
So your `progress` is always 1 because `operation.progress` is always positive. 
Try to simplify your progress calculation:

```
IEnumerator load(){
    yield return null;

    //Begin to load the Scene you specify
    AsyncOperation asyncOperation = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(sceneIndex);
    //Don't let the Scene activate until you allow it to
    asyncOperation.allowSceneActivation = false;
    Debug.Log("Pro :" + asyncOperation.progress);
    //When the load is still in progress, output the Text and progress bar
    while (!asyncOperation.isDone)
    {
        //Output the current progress
        Debug.Log("Loading progress: " + (asyncOperation.progress * 100) + "%");

        // Check if the load has finished
        if (asyncOperation.progress >= 0.9f)
        {
            //Change the Text to show the Scene is ready
            asyncOperation.allowSceneActivation = true;
        }

        yield return null;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: It works for me (Unity 2019.2.6f1). And it works for 3 projects. What is your Unity Editor version?

Comment: The version is ```2019.2.8.f1```

Comment: I tried checking the fps, and it goes down to 3 or even 1 fps. This, as I said, is probably the problem. I would need to keep a good amount of fps even when loading a scene!

Comment: Code-only answers are frowned upon. Please explain what you fixed, and why this change solves the issue at hand.

Answer (score -1):

If it's super important to show this loading bar, you may need to implement it by showing a platform native UI widget.